# Ubuntu 23.04: How to connect a MIDI keyboard always to the same MIDI device ID?

Tags: 22.10, midi, 23.04

I have a MIDI keyboard connected to a computer running Ubuntu 23.04 (the problem already existed under 22.10). At boot time, the MIDI keyboard is connected either as `/dev/midi1` or `/dev/midi2`. Every time the ID changes, I have to reconfigure the keyboard connection in the sampler software. That's annoying!

Is it possible to always give a MIDI device the same ID when booting Ubuntu?

**Edit:**

This is the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`.

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7f10000 irq 31
 1 [controller     ]: USB-Audio - Renatus keyboard controller
                      Renatus ltd Renatus keyboard controller at usb-0000:00:14.0-10, full speed
 2 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e40000 irq 32
```

Yesterday the MIDI device was connected to `midi2`, today it is again `midi1`.

Could it be that it depends on whether the monitor is on or off at startup? I will test that. No, this does not seem to have any impact.

Comment: Please show the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`.